# Problems with TLS Android - Netty

Tags: java, android, ssl, netty

I'm working on Android client for client-server application. I need TLS session with server with mutual authentication. I use Netty on the server. My client code:

```
// private key
File client_tls_key =  new File("/sdcard/GreatParents/tls/client_key.pkcs8");

KeyManagerFactory kmf = null;
KeyStore ks;
try {
    ks = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
    ks.load(new FileInputStream("/sdcard/GreatParents/tls/client_ks.bks"), "changeit".toCharArray());
    String kmf_type = KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
    kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(kmf_type);
    kmf.init(ks, "changeit".toCharArray());
} catch (KeyStoreException | CertificateException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | IOException | UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
TrustManagerFactory tmf = null;
KeyStore ts;
try {
    ts = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
    ts.load(new FileInputStream("/sdcard/GreatParents/tls/client_ts.bks"), "changeit".toCharArray());
    String tmf_type = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
    tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmf_type);
    tmf.init(ts);
} catch (KeyStoreException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if (tmf != null) {
    SslContext sslCtx = null;
    try {
        sslCtx = SslContext.newClientContext(SslProvider.JDK,null,tmf,null,client_tls_key,keypass,kmf,null,IdentityCipherSuiteFilter.INSTANCE,(ApplicationProtocolConfig) null,0,0);
    } catch (SSLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        logger.error("TLS Session not initialized");
        return;
    }
}
```

Server's certificate stores in file client_ts.bks. Client's certificate stores in file client_ks.bks.

I got Exception:

```
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyStore JKS implementation not found
```

I found in stacktrace method:

```
io.netty.handler.ssl.JdkSslContext.buildKeyManagerFactory
```

with code:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
```

Netty creates JKS-keystores forced, instead of using my BKS-keystores, right?! If I'm right, Netty doesn't compatible with Android in TLS part.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned that "JKS" is hard coded in Netty, they can use Keystore.getDefaultType() but not sure whether it may cause any problems or not.
Apart from that, there is a workaround to use TLS in Android using Netty. You could use JAVA's SSLContext and create new SslHandler to add in channel pipeline via SslHandler(SSLContext.createSSLEngine).

Something like this after initializing trust manager factory:

```
...

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(),tmf.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());
    SSLEngine sslEngine = sslContext.createSSLEngine();
    sslEngine.setUseClientMode(true);
    SslHandler sslHandler = new SslHandler(sslEngine);
    channel.pipeline().addFirst(sslHandler)

...
```